# next step get executed before current function callback get called

Tags: javascript, callback, gulp

Below is my gulp task:

```js
var validateCss = require("css-validator");
gulp.task("cssvalid", async function () {
  var files = glob.sync("src/styles/*.css");
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var filesource = fs.readFileSync(files[i], "utf8");
    checks(filesource);
  }
});

function checks(filesource) {
  validateCss({ text: filesource, profile: "css3svg" }, function (err, data) {
    if (data.errors.length == 0) {
      console.log("Success: " + files[i]);
      console.log("No errors or warnings\n");
    } else {
      data.errors.forEach(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + files[i] + ": line " + error.line);
        console.log(error.message + "\n");
      });
    }
  });
}
```

**Before my validateCss function's callback gets called, it goes for next `for loop`**, so that it wont throw css validation error properly

Comment: Have you tried to put "await" before glob.sync("src/styles/*.css")?

Comment: yes but no luck for me